# Python 3.4.2, using Tkinter buttons to return a variable to be used by the program

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am trying to create a tkinter GUI which assigns a value to a variable when a button is pressed, then returns that value to be used in the rest of the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def yes_command(ans):
    ans = 'yes' 
    window.destroy()
    return (ans)

def no_command(ans):
    ans = 'no'
    window.destroy()
    return (ans)

window = Tk()

yes_no_label = Label(window, text="Yes or no?")
yes_no_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

YESbutton = Button(window, text="Yes", fg='green', command = lambda :yes_command(ans))
YESbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)
NObutton = Button(window, text = 'No', fg = 'red', command= lambda :no_command(ans))
NObutton.grid(row=1, column=2)

window.mainloop()

print(ans)
```

In this, the GUI comes up and once a button is pressed, it does close. However, it does not output (as this is called outside of the function I know it would work if it printed).

What further confuses me is that if I were to replace *return (ans)* with *print (ans)* it will print. Surely this just means it will not allow the value to leave the function? In which case, why?

I would be grateful for any help, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `command=...` does not change `ans`.  You aren't storing `yes_command(...)` and `no_command(...)` in a variable, and neither is `Tkinter.Button`.  It *is* being called, but nothing stores what it returns.

Comment: You can't return something from a callback, because the code that calls the function (`mainloop()`) ignores returned values from callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution for your question. I use a global StringVar() variable. You can set global variable in any function and  print later.

```
from Tkinter import *
def yes_command():
    global answer
    answer.set('yes')
    window.destroy()

def no_command():
    global answer
    answer.set('no')
    window.destroy()

window = Tk()

yes_no_label = Label(window, text="Yes or no?")
yes_no_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

global answer
answer=StringVar()

YESbutton = Button(window, text="Yes", fg='green', command = lambda :yes_command())
YESbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)
NObutton = Button(window, text = 'No', fg = 'red', command= lambda :no_command())
NObutton.grid(row=1, column=2)

window.mainloop()

print(answer.get())
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you described the important changes. Otherwise the reader has to compare your code with the original line by line.

Comment: The three `global` statements are unnecessary. A global name can be reached from inside a function, and there is certainly no reason for the third `global`.

Comment: Yes i tried you are right. Program can work without  global variables

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class and handle a global value from there. I also added a new button named `Test ans value` to read the value of `ans` everytime you push the `Yes` or `No` button. I also commented the `.destroy()` lines so you can check how it works.

```
from tkinter import *

class UI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.ans = ''
        yes_no_label = Label(window, text="Yes or no?")
        yes_no_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        YESbutton = Button(window, text="Yes", fg='green', command =lambda:self.yes_command())
        YESbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)

        NObutton = Button(window, text = 'No', fg = 'red', command= lambda:self.no_command())
        NObutton.grid(row=1, column=2)

        checkValue = Button(window, text = 'Test ans value', command= lambda:self.test_value())
        checkValue.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def yes_command(self):
        self.ans = 'yes'      
        #window.destroy()

    def no_command(self):
        self.ans = 'no'
        #window.destroy()

    def test_value(self):
        print self.ans     

window = Tk()
newUI = UI(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the ideas, I have taken a simple version, then tested it by calling it, adding it to a variable, then outputting that to test that the value re-assigns:

```
from tkinter import *

def YNquestion():
    global answer
    def yes_command():
        answer.set('yes')
        window.destroy()

    def no_command():
        answer.set('no')
        window.destroy()

    window = Tk()

    yes_no_label = Label(window, text="Yes or no?")
    yes_no_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    answer=StringVar()

    YESbutton = Button(window, text="Yes", fg='green', command = lambda   :yes_command())
    YESbutton.grid(row=1, column=0)
    NObutton = Button(window, text = 'No', fg = 'red', command= lambda :no_command())
    NObutton.grid(row=1, column=2)

    window.mainloop()

YNquestion()
choice = answer.get()
print(choice)
YNquestion()
choice = answer.get()
print(choice)
```

If I press Yes the first time around and No the second time around, it prints correctly. In this version I removed the unnecessary uses of *global*. It works perfectly, thanks for all the help!